# jQuery tablesorter grouping subtotals for child rows only

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

[image]I need to have the group subtotals display in the group header rows of my table. Everything is working fine except the math. Inside each group, I have expanding parent rows that contain the total of all child rows for that parent. When I total my groups, it adds all parent & child rows together, giving me a total that is 2x the number I am looking for. Is there a way to add ONLY the child rows, or ONLY the parent rows? Here's what I have so far:

```
group_callback: function($cell, $rows, column, table) {
   if (column === column) {
      var t, successesTotal = 0;
      $rows.each(function() {
            successesTotal += parseInt($(this).parent('td').eq(successesColumn).text());
});
```

I have tried a few different ways that seem logical but none of them seem to work.

```
successesTotal += parseInt($(this).find('tbody tr.tablesorter-childRow td').eq(successesColumn).text());
```

Didn't work. Neither did:

```
$rows.each(function() {
     if ($('tr').hasClass('tablesorter-childRow')) {
         successesTotal += parseInt($(this).parent('td').eq(successesColumn).text());
 });
```

I am SO close to having this work exactly as I need it but I still need to exclude the parent rows from the calculation & it will be perfect. In the image attached, the bolded lines are the parent rows displaying the totals of their child rows. Successes should be 165 & total lines should be 6 (or 2, either way will work for me!) I have spent almost 2 full days now trying to get around this. Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

As requested, here is the table HTML (modified for simplification):

```
<table class="tablesorter">
   <thead>
     <th class="group-word">Column1</th>
     <th class="group-false filter-parsed">Column2</th>
     <th class="group-false filter-parsed">Column3</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Category1</td>
         <td><a href="#" class="toggle">Category2</a></td>
         <td>Subtotal1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
         <td>ChildData1</td>
         <td>ChildData2</td>
         <td>ChildData3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
         <td>ChildData1</td>
         <td>ChildData2</td>
         <td>ChildData3</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I want to add ChildData3 with ChildData3. I need to exclude SubTotal1.

Comment: If it makes a difference, I used Mottie's fork of tablesorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$rows` parameter in the `group_callback` provides both the parent and all child rows, so you'll need to filter out one or the other.

```
// only target child rows
$rows.filter('.tablesorter-childRow')
```

Here is the code from [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4ac5kr3o/53/)

```
var successesColumn = 0;
$("#table").tablesorter({
  theme: "blue",
  widgets: ["group", "filter", "zebra"],
  widgetOptions: {
   group_collapsible : true,
    group_callback: function($cell, $rows, column, table) {
      if (column === successesColumn) {
        var t, successesTotal = 0;
        $rows.filter('.tablesorter-childRow').each(function() {
          successesTotal += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(successesColumn).text(), 10);
        });
        $cell.find(".group-count").append("; Successes: " + successesTotal );
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Other fixes:

- The `$rows` variable has `tr`s in it, so use `.find('td')` instead of parent.
- It's a good habit to get into to add a radix of `10` when using `parseInt` for decimal integers ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt))

Comment: Mottie - This is perfect. Thank you so much!! While I understood what I was trying to do, I couldn't figure out for the life of me how accomplish it. This was exactly what I needed. I was also able to apply that same filter to the group_count to display the correct number of lines too.

Comment: PS - Love your fork of tablesorter. Really nice functionality :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the proper way to add this but I am having trouble adding the pagination to it. I am getting the following error: $table.tablesorter(...).tablesorterPager is not a function

Comment: I double checked & i have loaded jquery, jquery.tablesorter.js, widget-storage.js, widget-filter.js, widget-grouping.js, jquery.tablesorter.pager.js, widget-pager.js before calling .tableSorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); but I am still getting the error. I'm guessing a namespace error. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need `widget-pager` if you are using the addon. Please verify that the pager addon is loading - check the path and filename - and that only one version of jQuery is being loaded.

Comment: I didn't have the add-on loading properly. Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through every row in the table you could try looping through just the child rows like this

`$('.tablesorter-childRow').each(function() {});`

**EDIT**

[Check out this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxxkn2Lw/37/)

Comment: Thanks but no luck. This way does grab just the child rows but it totals the whole table & not the individual groups. I also tried putting this line inside of the $rows.each function & vice versa to try to keep the grouping functionality but that gives me either 0 or NaN.

Comment: You can add a class to the parent row's successesColumn, something like  'groupTotal'. This way you can add all of the values for class 'groupTotal'.

Comment: It's just your standard HTML table with a couple of classes added. It's the jquery plugin that I'm having a problem with.